# hash<T>, less<T> functions: Empty parenthesis after template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11

Going through the book C++ Primer 5th edition, I am confused as to what the syntax is exactly saying. Particularly, I'm curious about the empty () after template parameter list in less<> and hash<>.

```
hash<string>()(s.bookNo); // () after <string>

less<T>()(v1, v2);
```

I am guessing it creating a function insantiation and passing parameters in the last set of () i.e. (s.bookNo)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`hash<T>` and `less<T>` are not functions - they are classes. `less<T>()` creates a temporary instance of the class; `(v1, v2)` then calls its `operator()` member function on that instance.

Comment: Very interesting. So is it calling the class's default constructor?  I had known the Class_Type var1(constr_params); syntax but this temporary object one is new for me. Good to know. Thanks.